# Is 'Include /path/to/*/live.conf' possible with Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

We store VirtualHost entries in (dev|staging|live).conf files within the SVN repository for the site.

For example:

```
/var/www/vhosts/site1.com/live.conf
/var/www/vhosts/site2.com/live.conf
```

It'd be handy to be able to include them automatically, such as:
Include /var/www/vhosts/*/live.conf

But that doesn't seem to work.

We've worked around it with a simple PHP script:

```
$vhosts = '';
foreach (glob('/var/www/vhosts/*/vhost/dev.conf') as $filename) {
    $vhosts .= "\nInclude $filename";
}

file_put_contents('/var/www/vhosts/vhosts.conf', $vhosts);
```

However, I'd love to simplify and get Apache (2.2.3) to do the job without requiring the PHP step.

Possible?

Answer (score 3):

apache2 does not support wildcards in includes.
However, you could arrange it a bit in the following manner:

- create some directory for your configs (such as /etc/apache2/myconfigs)
- symlink your configuration dynamically to apache2:

> ```
> rm -f /etc/apache2/myconfigs/*
> for i in $(find /var/www/vhosts/*/live.conf); do \
> tempfn=$(echo $i|cut -d/ -f5-6|sed s,/,_,);  \
> ln -s $i /etc/apache2/myconfigs/$tempfn.conf \
> done
> ```

- add a "Include /etc/apache2/myconfigs" in your apache2.conf

Note: on cut, i used -f5-6 for delimiter joining (to provide something like site1.com_live.conf symlink name), but you might have to adjust that according to your own fs path.
Note on note: the above is for **bash**, might need adapting for other shells.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested, it through the below error when checking syntax:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 211 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
>   Wildcard patterns not allowed in Include /etc/httpd/*/pr.conf

According to the documentation, from version 2.0.41, it supports the wildcard matching follow shell-style (fnmatch()). But it seems that it only works with the file (or the last component in the path), not the directory.

Testing with python, it returns true:

```
In [1]: import fnmatch

In [2]: fnmatch.fn
fnmatch.fnmatch      fnmatch.fnmatchcase  

In [2]: fnmatch.fnmatch('/etc/httpd/site1.com/live.conf','/etc/httpd/*/live.conf')
Out[2]: True
```

Comment: According to my apache 2.2.19:
apache2: Syntax error on line 229 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Wildcard patterns not allowed in Include /etc/apache2/conftest/*/a.conf

Comment: My 2.2.12 on Ubuntu and 2.2.3 on CentOS 5 gives me `Wildcard patterns not allowed in Include`

Comment: It looks like wildcards are only allowed in the last component of the path.

Answer (score 2):

`mod_perl` allows for the following construct:

```
<Perl>
    foreach $file (glob '/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts/*/live.conf') {
        push @Include, $file;
    }
</Perl>
```

This can be used in place of the `Include` directive.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem for a while and have written a blog post on how to fix it by applying some patches to apache, I hope it helps.  I works for me :)

http://wes.limethinking.co.uk/2011/09/07/apache-include-directive-wildcards-in-directory-names/